# Can I block the true IP address using X-Forwarded-For header in IIS?

Tags: network, web-application, http

All the traffic gets to my IIS server through a proxy. I can't block or white list IP addresses because all the traffic comes from the proxy's IP address.

Can I use the X-Forwarded-For header with IIS?

Comment: You should be blocking people at the proxy instead.

Answer (score 5):

I would proceed with caution using a HTTP header for IP filtering considering they can be controlled by the client unless your webserver takes this in account when it forwards your request.

What happens if I as not authorized send X-Forwarded-For in my headers? Will your webserver add an extra X-Forwarded-For? Will it add it below or above mine? Which one will the IIS use to validate on?

These are questions you need to be able to answer before implementing any trust in the header value.

**Edit**: I dont know of a better alternative, but if you are going for the one you're question you should be able to answer the questions first. I am not talking about passing through multiple proxies, but instead what happens if I put my own X-Forwarder-For header on the bottom of my request? Will your proxy add another one further up? Will there be two X-Forwarder-For? Which one will the webserver look at?

Comment: First, can you suggest a better alternative? Second, it does not work like this, the web server wont add this header at all!! this header is added by proxies.And it does not work like this, if the request passes through multiple proxies, each proxy wont add another "x-forwarded-for" header, it would append to the value of the first header.

Comment: on the proxy, strip any X-Forwarded-For prior to appending one with the clients IP.

Comment: If you manually add the x-forwarded header to your request when you send it, my proxy wont add another header, it will add its IP to the header value that you added, it will look like this (X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.0.1, 172.16.0.1, 10.0.0.1). In addition, some proxies can be configured to accept requests with x-forwarded-header from specific IPs as well.

Comment: @Bahi, Then you need to know what IP address to look for in that chain. Because I spoof my X-Header-For, and you add my real one then your IIS need to know which one to use. Both in normal cases and in extreme cases (for example if I add another 2 X-Header-For).

Comment: I hope my question gets answered first, if IIS can use XFF header to block IPs....Then I promise you I will pay attention to the other stuff :)

Comment: @Bahi, ah sorry I realised that was the original question now; if it is actually possible. I've looked into some scripts that rewrites the c_ip field in the log with the X-Forwarded-For IP. You can potentially use this for something? http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/12/23/x-forwarded-for-http-module-for-iis7-source-included.aspx

Answer (score 2):

IIS 7 and beyond include the [Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions) module, which supports filtering client requests by their `X-Forwarded-For` header, which is added to a request [when using an AWS load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for):

> Support for web servers behind a proxy - If your web server is behind a proxy, you can configure the module to use the client IP address from an X-Forwarded-For header.

[You can enable Proxy Mode support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions#support-for-web-servers-behind-proxy) by checking the "Proxy" checkbox in the module's configuration page, then write rules to allow/deny IPs/CIDR ranges via the module.

Comment: When you enable "Proxy" mode, any dynamic rules [are skipped for "Allowed" IPs and CIDRs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996079/241211) in the `X-Forwarded-For` chain. Are you saying that "Denied" IPs and CIDRs found in the chain will be summarily blocked? (i.e. Irrespective of the "dynamic" rate limiting, concurrent requests, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6796165/241211) at Stack Overflow is nominally asking the same thing.

You can use the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to do your filtering by adding a condition around the `{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}` variable as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6816893/241211)

Alternatively, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700152/241211) describes a method by which you can set the IP address *back to its pre-proxy value* with a global rewrite rule. (I personally think that if you do that, you might want to add an `X-Forwarded-By` header as well.) Then you can write normal rules of whatever sort you like to do the filtering.

In general, however, I agree with the [comment by vcsjones](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5149/can-i-block-the-true-ip-address-using-x-forwarded-for-header-in-iis#comment8394_5149) on your question wherein s/he suggests that you do this filtering at the proxy, if that's an available option.

Answer (score 0):

[ModSecurity](http://modsecurity.org/) has this capability since it has full visibility of the transaction.  Meaning it can inspect headers and payload in both the request and response. Just need to create a rule for this condition.  There's one caveat, although ModSecurity was written by Microsoft and Trustwave it is considered community support.  If this is a production application, you won't be able to call Microsoft Support for assistance.  With that, the mailing lists for ModSecurity are great and the Trustwave engineers are very helpful.  If you need paid support for rules, Trustwave has a service offering this as well as a commercial ruleset (similar to the snort model).

Other Web Application Firewalls (WAF) would work but ModSecurity is free.

Answer (score 0):

I use web.config to show empty.html (empty file) for IP which is harassing my website.
This is not IP block on network level (FW) but stop execution of page creation and shows blank screen.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="BlockRemoteIP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" pattern="111\.222\.333\.444" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/empty.html" />
        </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Put empty.html in root directory of your website for rewrite to work.

Comment: You don't need an _empty.html_ file. Just abort the request with `<action type="AbortRequest" />` or send them the 404 directly with `<action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Not Found" statusDescription="Page not found."/>`. (Also, add `\b`s around your IP address so that `1\.2\.3\.4` doesn't match `111\.2\.3\.4`.)